# elpy with Winpython: how to configure?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to setup elpy for emacs on my windows system, on which I'm using Winpython 3.4.3.

I have installed all the dependencies such as rope, flake8, etc... using pip. When I type `M-x elpy-config` in emacs, I get "Neither easy_install nor pip found".

If I run `(executable-find "python")` then I get the correct path to my Winpython installation.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 with Emacs 24.5 and Python 2.7 it worked for me to include the actual directory containing pip (Scripts) in the `exec-path`; using `M-x customize-variable exec-path`. Apparently, including just the directory of the python executable was not enough.